# Hausdorffness being preserved under continuous 1-1 function or not

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let
$$f: X \rightarrow Y$$

be a continuous $1-1$ function. Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff, is $Y$ necessarily Hausdorff? And vis versa. So I have concluded that the case where if $Y$ is Hausdorff then $X$ is Hausdorff is true. To see this suppose $x_1,x_2 \in X$ . As $f$ is $1-1$, the preimages are disjoint and we have we have that

$$f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$$

Thus there exists open sets $V_1,V_2 \subset Y$ (by Hausdorff property of $Y$) with $f(x_1) \in V_1, f(x_2) \in V_2$ such that

$$V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$$

Then by continuity of $f$, $f^{-1}(V_1),f^{-1}(V_2) \subset X$ are open and they are disjoint and since $f$ is $1-1$. And we have

$$x_1 \in f^{-1}(V_1), x_2 \in f^{-1}(V_2)$$

Making $X$ Hausdorff. I tried hard to think of a continuous mapping from a Hausdorff space into a non-Hausdorff space. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find a version, they all had $X$ being compact and $f$ being homeo.

Comment: Take $X$ to be a singleton, and map it to any member of $Y$.  Or do you want $f$ to be surjective?

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily have to be onto, but what set/topology on $Y$? can I take the cofinite topology on $\Bbb{R}$? @RobertIsrael

Comment: $Y$ can be any topological space you want.

Comment: @RobertIsrael is my proof correct for the part that assumes $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose X is Hausdorff, is Y necessarily Hausdorff?

No. Even its image doesn't have to be. Consider any topological space $Y$ and the identity $Y\to Y$ with the discrete topology on the left side.

Comment: so could I put the cofinite topology on the right?

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' sure. On an infinite set.

Comment: Is my proof for the other part correct?

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' yes, it is correct.